# nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Export identifier [meeting_window_meetings] encountered more than once

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

This is how my class looks like :

**crm/model/meetingwindow/MeetingWindowMeeting.java**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "meeting_window_meetings")
public class MeetingWindowMeeting {

    @Column(name = "meeting_window_id")
    private Long meetingWindowId;

    @Column(name = "meetings_id")
    @Id
    private Long meetingId;
}
```

The application fails to start and throws error :

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaAuditingHandler': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Export identifier [meeting_window_meetings] encountered more than once`

I am unable to figure out what is causing this error and how to fix this?

Any help on how to go about this?

Comment: based on naming convention I would say TC is trying to map auxiliary table, which backs up `@ManyToAny` or `@OneToMany` association, to independent entity.

Comment: If that is true and you really need such mapping, place `@Immutable` over class and replace `@Table(name = "meeting_window_meetings")` with `@Subselect("select meeting_window_id, meetings_id from meeting_window_meetings")`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov The mappings are needed as this is Junction table to `meeting` and `meeting_window` tables.

Comment: If `MeetingWindowMeeting` should represent a `@ManyToMany` relationship, then this class is not needed at all, as you would use `@JoinTable` annotation to define the mapping